# Ruby on Rails convert list to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

the following query return as follow:

```
@cref = Creference.all
@cref = @cref.group_by{|cc| cc["name"]}

result: Object {US: Array[1], UK: Array[1]}
```

And these query return the result as:

```
@countries = Product.joins(:user).distinct.where("state is not null and country <> ''").where(:users => {:merchant_status => 1}).pluck(:country)
@countries.map! {|country| country.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')}
@countries = @countries.uniq

result: ["US", "UK"]
```

I am using `gon` to pass the result to the country drop down list:

```
gon.search_location_list = @countries +  @cref
```

How can I make the first result format to match the second one?  Thanks!!!

Comment: hey you can use as `@countries +  @cref.keys`

Comment: Vishal is right. This is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the first result format to match the second one?

In your first example you are using `group_by` which returns a Hash. In second example you are using `map` which returns an Array. Use the same thing both places to get similar format.

```
@cref = @cref.map{|cc| cc["name"]}
# ["US", "UK"]
```

Answer (score 0):

After your first two lines, add this line:

```
@cref = @cref.values
```

Answer (score 0):

In short you question is that you want to concatenate array values with hash keys. So for this the simplest solution is

```
@cref = @cref.group_by{|cc| cc["name"]}.keys
```

This would return the keys in array format and than you can concatenate. But that would result is same value but you can call uniq() on it.